# Weird static initialization in Java when using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, static, initialization

Given the following code-snippet I get the output "B" and "error":

```
public class Test {

    private static class A {
        static final B c = new B();
    }

    private static class B extends A {
        static final B c = A.c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(Class<?> cls : Test.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            if(cls.getDeclaredFields()[0].get(null) == null) {
                System.out.println(cls.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        if(B.class.getDeclaredField("c").get(null) == null) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

}
```

But it gets even more bizarre. If I comment-out the for-loop I get no output - so no error. Also if I access the field B.c directly without reflection before doing the reflection stuff the problem does not occur.
Why is that so and how can I fix it?

Comment: I would refactor the code to remove the circular dependency between the two classes.  This would almost certainly fix your problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related with reflection, is related with the order in which classes are initialized.

If class A is initialized first, it has a dependency in class B, class B tries to initialize B.c to a static field of A, but this field is still null.

If the class B is initialized first, it has a dependency in class A, the class A is initialized and A.c is set to a new B instance and B.c is initialized correctly.

To make an example more simple, this code shows the problem simplified:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(A.c);
    System.out.println(B.c);
}
```

Output:

```
Test$B@f72617
null
```

And this other example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(B.c);
    System.out.println(A.c);
}
```

Output:

```
Test$B@f72617
Test$B@f72617
```

To solve the problem you could change your design to remove the circular dependency or make sure the classes are initialized in the right order.

Comment: Close.  However, the problem is not with the order in which classes are *loaded*.  It is in the order that they are *initialized*.  Or more precisely, the order in which the respective classes' static initialization occurs.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for your comment. That was my point. I reworded my answer to try to be more precise with the terms.